# SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync throws IOException

Tags: c#, stream, serial-port, ioexception

When I try to send data to the serial port, it works fine. But when I try to read one byte from the port, reading operation immediately throws IOException (Additional information: Reached the end of the file). I use the following code:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[1];
await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buff, 0, 1); // Exception arises here
```

I tried to set `port.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 1000` after configuring the port, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Call stack of [main thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkSKL.png) and [another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYZlT.png). Btw, not sure if this is incorrect, but local variables values in non-main thread never appear in the debugging window, neither before exception arises nor after.

Comment: [Copy the exception details to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and add them to your question as a edit.

Comment: I think this option is absent in VS 2012+, but I can show [excaption object state](http://i.imgur.com/WDpLV6V.png) and [stack trace](http://i.imgur.com/MhL25j4.png).

Comment: Is there any data to be read?  Kind of sounds like it's trying to read something that doesn't exist and it's throwing an exception.

Comment: I suggest to read from buffer only if the buffer is not empty, therefore I suggest to use
if serialport.BytesToRead > 0
    'do stuff
end if

Personally, I don't like the readAsync ... I prefer to instantiate a DataReceived Event.